# Leer JSON con Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

Mediante Ajax recibo un JSON con usuarios y características, no consigo leer json que recibo por AJAX este concretamente

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","nombre":"Juan","titulo":"Color de los ojos","valor":"azul oscuro"},{"id":"1","nombre":"Juan","titulo":"Color del coche","valor":"azul claro"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Irene","titulo":"Color de los ojos","valor":"azulados"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Irene","titulo":"Color de la casa","valor":"azul"},{"id":"6","nombre":"Teresa","titulo":"Color de los ojos","valor":"verdes azulados"}]}
```

Quiero recorrer el JSON para sacar todos los valores por pantalla formateado de la manera que yo quiera, pero no encuentro manera de acceder a los valores.

La función con la que recibo el JSON es esta:

```
$(document).ready( function() {   
    $("#enviar").click( function() {     
        if(validaForm()){  
            $.get("../api/index.php",$("#formdata").serialize(),function(json){
                if(json){

                
                 // AQUI QUIERO LEER EL json

                } else {
                    $("#fracaso").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");    
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Solamente tienes que acceder a la propiedad result :/

```js
let json = {
        "result": [{
            "id": "1",
            "nombre": "Juan",
            "titulo": "Color de los ojos",
            "valor": "azul oscuro"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
            "nombre": "Juan",
            "titulo": "Color del coche",
            "valor": "azul claro"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "nombre": "Irene",
            "titulo": "Color de los ojos",
            "valor": "azulados"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "nombre": "Irene",
            "titulo": "Color de la casa",
            "valor": "azul"
        }, {
            "id": "6",
            "nombre": "Teresa",
            "titulo": "Color de los ojos",
            "valor": "verdes azulados"
        }]
    };
    
    for (let prop of json.result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prop));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accedes a la propiedad result que contiene el array y lo recorres.

En el ejemplo hay comentarios explicativos:

```
$.get("../api/index.php", $("#formdata").serialize(), function (json) {
    if (json) {
        // AQUI QUIERO LEER EL json
        // transformas los datos de la respuesta a un objeto javascript.
        let data = JSON.parse(json)

        // accedes a la propiedad result y recorres el array.
        data.result.forEach(user => {
            console.log(user.nombre)
        });

    } else {
        $("#fracaso").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```